# UnknownError accessing pages from OneNote

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote

I am connecting to Notebooks stored on SharePoint and getting "UnknownError" using the Graph API when trying to retrieve Pages.

I have **no problem querying notebooks, sections or sectiongroups** - that's all working, so no authentication problems or anything

Request:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{app id}/onenote/pages
```

Error below:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "65721acc-f0d9-40d6-bf80-aac1507a6c2f",
            "date": "2018-01-02T17:34:21"
        }
    }
}
```

Graph explorer returns this after about 30 seconds, so I'm guessing it's timing out. There are about 10 notebooks in the site I'm connecting to, which each have several hundred pages

I do only need to return 1 page at a time in almost every case. I have tried adding a `$filter=` at the end, but get the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly recommend to get pages for each section rather than getting all the pages that the user has access to.

Please refer to the bottom 2 recommendations in this article: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/onenotedev/2017/07/21/a-few-performance-tips-for-using-the-onenote-api/

Comment: Thanks for the link Manjusha, but I'm still having an issue with it timing out on large sections.

I've tried the suggested GET ~/sections/{id}/pages call.

Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesnt, based on the number of pages. Some sections have hundreds of pages

Comment: If you don't need the LastModifiedDateTime for the pages, please use the $select and $orderby clauses which will further optimize your request processing. For example: GET ~/sections/{id}/pages?$select=id,name,creationDate&$orderby=creationDate

Comment: The timeouts turned out to be a local issue. I'm using RestSharp, I just set RestClient.Timeout to a higher number. To avoid performance issues for our front-end application, I ended up storing our entire hierarchy locally to locate sections quickly. We have over 1000 sections across 10 notebooks which fortunately don't often change. We then got a list of pages using Manjusha's suggestion